# Why does data-live-search not work in a simple example

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I try the code below on bootply.com it just appears as a normal dropdown and I do not get the live search box. What am I missing?

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" >
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Alaska </option>
    <option>Arizona </option>
    <option>Arkansas </option>
    <option>California </option>
    <option>Colorado </option>
    <option>Connecticut </option>
    <option>Delaware </option>
    <option>Florida </option>
    <option>Georgia </option>
    <option>Hawaii </option>
    <option>Idaho </option>
    <option>Illinois Indiana </option>
    <option>Iowa </option>
    <option>Kansas </option>
    <option>Kentucky </option>
    <option>Louisiana </option>
    <option>Maine </option>
    <option>Maryland </option>
    <option>Massachusetts </option>
    <option>Michigan </option>
    <option>Minnesota </option>
    <option>Mississippi </option>
    <option>Missouri </option>
    <option>Montana Nebraska </option>
    <option>Nevada </option>
    <option>New Hampshire </option>
    <option>New Jersey </option>
    <option>New Mexico </option>
    <option>New York </option>
    <option>North Carolina </option>
    <option>North Dakota </option>
    <option>Ohio </option>
    <option>Oklahoma </option>
    <option>Oregon </option>
    <option>Pennsylvania Rhode Island </option>
    <option>South Carolina </option>
    <option>South Dakota </option>
    <option>Tennessee </option>
    <option>Texas </option>
    <option>Utah </option>
    <option>Vermont </option>
    <option>Virginia </option>
    <option>Washington </option>
    <option>West Virginia </option>
    <option>Wisconsin </option>
    <option>Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-live-search` is not a Bootstrap option or component so it's not just going to work. You need to use a 3rd party component such as https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the bootstrap-select plugin: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Examples in the official documentation:
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

where you can find out how the attribute "data-live-search" works.